# Digital Microscope(equivalent to an old webcam) on MacOS

Tags: mac, drivers, webcam, camera

I have this "DM4 Digital Microscope" (noname?):
[image: DM4 microscope]

(readily available on e.g. eBay)

I can not make it work on my mac!

The microscope is set up to works as an external camera, and...

*It has been successfully tested on a millennial old windows XP computer*.

On my newly restarted and fully upgraded(macOS Catalina 10.15.4) MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2019), the camera identifies in System report as:

> GENERAL - UVC :
>
> Model ID:   UVC Camera VendorID_6975 ProductID_8194   Unique
>   ID:   0x141000001b3f2002

In 'Photo Booth'/Facetime the camera can be selected from the menu as "GENERAL - UVC", but there is no image or any error messages.

I can not find the vendor or any general driver for mac. I tried to install [manycam](https://manycam.com), as someone suggested here: https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/100897-webcam-support-limited-by-apples-uvc-driver-partially-solved/?page=7 - it gave the same result as 'Photo Booth'/Facetime, but now with the message "unknown error".

Almost everything point in the direction that UVC cameras,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_video_device_class should just work under mac. I did found it written somewhere that it should not be expected that very old UVC cameras could still work. Many people have trouble controlling their UVC cameras(focus, ...), but I just want an image.

[Macam](http://webcam-osx.sourceforge.net) does not work on 64 bit systems, and I do not know if it would have helped me.
[Softonic](https://usb-webcam-driver.en.softonic.com/mac/download) might have some generic webcam driver, but there are no description and I do not trust their software.

Any ideas to what I can try?

---

**Edit:**

Apparently the microscope came with software on a small CD. I do not have any CD drive, so I threw it out long time ago. Also - I do not know if there is anything for mac on the CD!? -or anything useful!? I am unable to find it anywhere online.

Comment: [WebCam Settings](http://mactaris.blogspot.com/) might do it, but there's no free trial, so you may have to take a punt for 8 bucks. I use it here for an unsupported old Logitech UVC cam on Mojave [& for many years prior]

Comment: @Tetsujin: Thank you, but it will not solve my problem. - This is witten in the description for WebCam Settings: " Your USB webcam must be working on your Mac properly (function normally with FaceTime, iChat/Messages, and Skype) before it can be used with Webcam Settings.".

Comment: Try running Windows in VM on the Mac: From Amazon, https://www.amazon.com/Microscope-10X-1000X-Magnification-Soldering-Appraisal/dp/B07LHJ8BB6 : " can not [sic] support ios system", and "
I have not been able to connect this to any software for my macbook".

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: I installed VirtualBox from these instructions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAspvheYHzQ and gave the box access to my usb device. In MS paint, I get this error "creation of the video preview failed please check the device connection and make sure that the device is not being used by another application or user"

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Nicely found that others also report problems on mac. -that is more than what I was able to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try the built-in Photo Booth app.  In the Photo Booth menu bar, select Camera, and switch camera from "FaceTime HD camera (built-in)" to "USB2.0 UVC PC Camera".

Comment: you need a usb driver for this, otherwise system won't see it